# subsetting complete cases of a dataframe in a list of dataframe

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes called mylist.
This list contains 300 dataframes.
I need to subset each one of these for their complete cases.

I am very new to R, i started studying it 2 weeks ago, and I tried just this:

```
mylist[[1]] [[!(complete.cases(mylist[[1]])),]]
```

but it doesn't seem to work, as

```
Error in `[[.data.frame`(mylist[[1]], !(complete.cases(mylist[[1]])),  : 
  argument "..2" is missing, with no default
```

I am searching on the web, but probably I am not asking the right question.
If someone would help me, even only reporting a link where I can take a look to the right function, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
lapply(mylist,function(x){x[complete.cases(x),]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) x[!rowSums(is.na(x)),])
```